# TableSorter consecutive search

Tags: tablesorter

It appears that tablesorter needs filter terms to match consecutively.

For example:
A column contains: "Safe Rigging Practices for Seafarers"

Filter:

"Safe" returns the column

"Safe Rigging" returns the column

"Safe Practices" does not return the column.

Is there an option to change this behavior?

Comment: Can you add wildcards ?  Maybe %Rigging% would return the column

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if that will work or not, but we can't ask our customers to use special search characters.

Comment: Could you just append % as both a prefix and suffix of all of their searches? They wouldnt have to put it in themselves.

Comment: Is there an option for adding wildcards to the search in tablesorter?

Comment: Ive never used the jQuery tablesorter itself, but have used other sorting and filter algorithms and they 'Usually' support wildcards of some type. I apologize if tablesorter does not support wildcards and this has led you in the wrong direction. I would have to read the documentation to know for sure.

Comment: I'm searching for that in the docs, now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a basic filter search, it only looks for a match of the query (from left-to-right), as you have stated above.

The filter widget also includes several different search types. See a full list in the docs at the top of [this demo page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html). Here are several ways to get the results you desire:

- As @vesuvious guessed, the search also supports wildcards, but in this case it uses an asterisk (`*`) to replace entire words (not including spaces). So try searching for:

  ```
  Safe * Practices
  ```
- You could also use a logical AND by separating words using two ampersands (`&&`), or the word "and" (case insensitive). Both must be surrounded by spaces:

  ```
  Safe && Practices
  Safe and Practices
  ```
- Lastly, you can use a fuzzy search to get the result by starting the search with a tilde (`~`):

  `~Safe Practices`

Comment: How do you add a built in filter to an external filter input        '$("#videoCourses").tablesorter({
            initWidgets: true,
            theme: 'bootstrap',
            widgets: ["zebra", "columns", "filter"],
            headers: { 0: { sorter: false } },
            sortList: [[0, 0]],
            widgetOptions: { filter_external: '.search', filter_columnFilters: false },
            headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}'
        });'

Comment: Use the [`filter_external` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-external), which it looks like you have in the code. Check out the documentation, because that external input MUST have a `data-column` attribute set.

Comment: Right. Got the data-column attribute in the input: <input class="search form-control" type="search" data-column="all"  placeholder="Search" /> Just don't know how to hook in the appropriate filter so the search will search on all words, not just consecutive ones. I must be missing something basic.

Comment: That should be all you need to do.. setting the `data-column="all"` will make that external search search on all words. All the associated filter types will work as well. If you're still having problems, please set up a demo and I'll try to help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much: http://jsfiddle.net/ricknew/zwmv6baf/10/  Just want to be able to type in  "Fire Prevent" and get the first item.

Comment: Oh, I see... the same filter rules apply, so use `~Fire Prevent`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, so how does the search filter character get injected without the user having to type it?